# Excel find lower distinct value in list

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find in a list the lowest unique value.
I tried to find out a way on google, but nothing seem to work like I want.

What i have :

```
John;5
Leon;7
Mark;5
Bob;3
Peter;3
Louis:4
```

Desired result: "4" because it's the lower unique value.

Suppose I add in the original list:

```
Alex;4
```

The new result is about to be "7" because it's the new lowest unique value.

my excel sheet :

[image: excel exemple]

Comment: How is this data formatted? in one or two columns? can we use a multiple step process?   does it need to be in VBA or formula or would any process based approach work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is setup so that names are in column A and values are in column B so that it looks like this:

[image: ex1]

In cell D2 (or wherever you want the result), use this **array** formula (Note that array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> and not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=MIN(IF(COUNTIF(B2:B20,B2:B20)=1,B2:B20))
```

You'll know you've entered it as an array formula correctly because you'll see it surrounded by curly braces `{=formula}`in the formula bar.  Do NOT add the curly braces manually.

You'll also notice that I have extra rows in there than just the used rows.  Normally I'd suggest using a dynamic named range, but this works for now.  So when you add the new line of Alex; 4, you get this:

[image: ex2]

And you can see the formula now has the new correct value of 7.

Comment: @logwin It looks like you have the French version of Excel. You'll need to use the French names for the formulas: `=MIN(SI(NB.SI(B2:B20,B2:B20)=1,B2:B20))`

Comment: I'm sorry but would you know how to display the name for value?

For exemple instead of 7 display Leon ?

Comment: Wrap it in an `INDEX` function: `=INDEX(A2:A20,MIN(SI(NB.SI(B2:B20,B2:B20)=1,B2:B20)))`

Comment: Erf it's not totally working because that take the value for number of line :/

Comment: oh right, need to pair it with Match: `=INDEX(A2:A20,EQUIV(MIN(SI(NB.SI(B2:B20,B2:B20)=1,B2:B20)),B2:B20,0))`

Answer (score 1):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,B1)
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter the **array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF(C:C=1,B:B))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

To avoid speed problems, make the limits on the ranges as small as possible:

**=MIN(IF(C1:C6=1,B1:B6**))

Comment: Unless the OP actually has data extending as far as row 1048576, an array formula which has to process that many rows' worth of data is not at all a good idea.